# add update and delete product methods not working in postman and not making any change in my database

Tags: asp.net-core

```css
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireLoggedIn", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin", "Customer", "Moderator").RequireAuthenticatedUser());

                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin").RequireAuthenticatedUser());
            });
```

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NG_Core_Auth.Data;
using NG_Core_Auth.Models;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace NG_Core_Auth.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;


        public ProductController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }


        // GET: api/values


        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        [Authorize(Policy = "RequireLoggedIn")]
        public IActionResult GetProducts()
        {
            return Ok(_db.Products.ToList());
        }



        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        [Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct([FromBody] ProductModel formdata)
        {
            var newproduct = new ProductModel
            {
                Name = formdata.Name,
                ImageUrl = formdata.ImageUrl,
                Description = formdata.Description,
                OutOfStock = formdata.OutOfStock,
                Price = formdata.Price
            };

            await _db.Products.AddAsync(newproduct);

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(new JsonResult("The Product was Added Successfully"));

        }


        [HttpPut("[action]/{id}")]
        [Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProduct([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] ProductModel formdata)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var findProduct = _db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == id);

            if (findProduct == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // If the product was found
            findProduct.Name = formdata.Name;
            findProduct.Description = formdata.Description;
            findProduct.ImageUrl = formdata.ImageUrl;
            findProduct.OutOfStock = formdata.OutOfStock;
            findProduct.Price = formdata.Price;

            _db.Entry(findProduct).State = EntityState.Modified;

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(new JsonResult("The Product with id " + id + " is updated"));

        }


        [HttpDelete("[action]/{id}")]
        [Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteProduct([FromRoute] int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            // find the product

            var findProduct = await _db.Products.FindAsync(id);

            if (findProduct == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _db.Products.Remove(findProduct);

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Finally return the result to client
            return Ok(new JsonResult("The Product with id " + id + " is Deleted."));

        }




    }
}
```

I work the controller with add update and delete methods I run the application and it run successfully with https://localhost:44301/ url then I make all the steps correctly in postman by adding https://localhost:44301/api/product/addproduct, putting headers and put the data I want to insert it in the body row and use post method I click send it return 401 Unauthorized, what is the problem ?
Iposted Productcontroller.cs and part of startup.cs files

Comment: Try to do a POST in Postman to your Login endpoint first. This will give the cookie to Postman that you are logged in (and what roles you have). Then next you should be able to POST successfully to your endpoints with `Authorize` attributes

Comment: Thank You man !!!!

Comment: No problem. I will add it as an answer since it worked for you.   :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a POST in Postman to your Login endpoint first. This will give the cookie to Postman that you are logged in (and what roles you have). Then next you should be able to POST successfully to your endpoints with `Authorize` attributes